# Error starting docker service: Unit not found

Tags: rhel, docker, socket

I am working with a Redhat 7.4, this machine doesn't have internet connection, and I want to install Docker, therefore I downloaded a rpm package, this one:

> docker-ce-selinux-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm

I used the command `yum install` and apparently all the process went fine but my issue begins when I use `sudo systemctl start docker` I get this:

> Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found.

I tried the solution in this topic: [Cannot start docker daemon in CentOS7 | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217526/cannot-start-docker-daemon-in-centos7) and my issue wasn't solved, I wrote this in the document docker.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API
PartOf=docker.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

when using the command `sudo systemctl start docker.socket` it throws this:

> Job for docker.socket failed. See "systemctl status docker.socket" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Then I used this command `sudo systemctl status docker.socket` and got this

```
docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; disabled; vendor 
preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream)

mar 02 10:19:28 machine.name systemd[1]: Socket service 
docker.service not loaded, refusing.
mar 02 10:19:28 machine.name systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Docker 
Socket for the API.
```

This is what I get when using `journalctl -xe`

```
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --
```

I am all stuck in this issue and I don't know what else to do/try; I am a bit new with Linux therefore I might be missing something.

**EDIT 1**

I've tried the command `rpm -qa | grep docker` and this is what I got:

> docker-ce-selinux-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must install a `Centos` package on `RHEL` then the package that you actually want is:

`docker-ce-17.12.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

You can download it elsewhere and then bring it over to your machine. The link to the package is 'https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-17.12.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

You will also need the package: `container-selinux-2.36-1.gitff95335.el7.noarch.rpm` as it is a dependency. It can be obtained from `http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/`

Before you begin, either `yum remove docker-ce-selinux-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm` or `rpm -e docker-ce-selinux-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm` as they may conflict with `container-selinux-2.36-1.gitff95335.el7.noarch.rpm`

After the packages I mentioned are on your machine, you can install them one of two ways:

`yum install container-selinux-2.36-1.gitff95335.el7.noarch.rpm docker-ce-17.12.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

`rpm -ivh container-selinux-2.36-1.gitff95335.el7.noarch.rpm docker-ce-17.12.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

After installation,

`systemctl list-unit-files | grep docker` which will show `docker.service`

`systemctl enable docker`

`systemctl start docker`

`systemctl status docker`

You will see the docker service started and running.

Comment: I will try on Monday since this is an issue at my work but in the mean time, may I know what's the difference between the package I installed and these packages you just told me?

Comment: The package that you installed is just the `selinux` dependency for the docker package. It's basically the same as the `container-selinux` package. You need the package I mentioned as it is the actual package for your docker usage.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help out!

Comment: In addition to these steps I had to install _pigz_ and after that it worked!